# Enviar variable POST y usarla para conexion PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quiero hacer lo siguiente. Tengo esta conexion:

```
<?php

$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'c1380069_id12345';
$username = 'c1380069_id12345';
$password = 'xxxxxxx';


try {   
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username , $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('Error en la conexión - Contacte con soporte    '.$e->getMessage() );
}

?>
```

Esta conexion funciona perfecto.
Lo que yo quiero hacer, es enviar por POST, un valor, en este caso es "id12345" que dependiendo del equipo puede variar.
El codigo quedaria asi.

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];

$server = 'localhost';
$database = 'c1380069_'.$id;
$username = 'c1380069_'.$id;
$password = 'xxxxxxx';


try {   
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username , $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('Error en la conexión - Contacte con soporte    '.$e->getMessage() );
}

?>
```

Si hago `echo $id`  imprime 'id12345' o sea que el parametro lo recibe bien, lo mismo si hago `echo $database` me muestra 'c1380069_id12345'.
pero al momento de hacer la conexion me muestra solo el valor sin la concatenacion. El error es el siguiente:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'c1380069_'@'172.17.110.255' (using password: YES)`

Aclaro nuevamente que si pongo el dato "id12345" de forma manual todo funciona a la perfeccion, pero mi idea es que es dato, vaya en un POST.
La consulta, es esto posible? Existe alguna regla de PHP o de los servidores web que no permita esta funcion?
En el servidor web estoy usando PHP 7.
Saludos y muchas gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Si haces `echo $username;` qué imprime? El mensaje de error hace pensar que no se está agregando el valor a `$username`, de todos modos, deberías hacer una evaluación del POST. La concatenación debería funcionar, creo que el problema es el POST. Igualmente si haces esto (a modo de prueba) debería funcionar: `$id='id12345'; $username = 'c1380069_';` De todos modos es rarísimo que quieres hacer esto y podría ser muy riesgoso. ¿Qué es lo que justifica que procedas así?

Comment: Hola! Si hago echo $username o $database (que tienen el mismo valor), me imprime 'c1380069_id12345' que es lo que necesito.En realidad, primero que nada soy un poco nuevo en php, pero mas alla de eso no me interesa mucho la seguridad ya que es solo para visualizacion de datos de unos equipos de uso interno, y mi intension es que si te logueas con el id 12345 se conecte a la base de datos 12345, si te logueas con el id uhh123 que se conecte a la base de datos uhh123. Sinceramente creo que no es la forma correcta de hacerla pero no conozco otra.

Comment: El valor "id" va por POST porque es un dato que se ingresa en un textbox

Comment: Intente tambien hacer un IF, en donde si el id recibido es "xxx" el $username y $database serian xxx, pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente, pero para que funcione, debe existir en la base de datos `c1380069_id12345` un usuario `c1380069_id12345` que tenga privilegios de conexión. Y en cuanto a la seguridad, creo que sería mejor tener un array asociativo con claves del tipo `"usuario"=>"baseDeDatos"` donde tengas a qué base de datos corresponde cada **posible** usuario. Así no dejas algo tan delicado exclusivamente al amparo de un POST. Sería una especie de lista blanca. Luego verificas si ese usuario existe y sacas del array la base de datos. **¿Y el password, es el mismo para todos los usuarios?**

Comment: Existe la base de datos y el usuario que me indicas compañero. Ambos tienen privilegios, recuerda que si los ingreso de forma manual funciona. El pass es el mismo para todos, como te digo, esto es solo para distintos equipos de uso interno, y solo para visualización de datos (valores de sensores) no hay nada sensible. Mas adelante me tomare el tiempo de investigar como dices, para darle mas seguridad, incluso tambien pense en incluir un token de seguridad, pero bueno, eso para mas adelante. Ahora me gustaria ver si se puede resolver esta cuestion

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te ocurre es curioso. He reproducido tu escenario para ver si PDO tenía alguna restricción en estos casos y me funciona perfectamente.

Procedo a indicar lo que he hecho:

## En el cliente

Un formulario que recoge el `id` y lo manda al servidor vía Ajax. He usado jQuery por simplicidad.

### Formulario:

```
<form id="myForm">
    Entre el ID:<input type="text" name="id" id="id">
  <button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

### Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {  
    $( "#btnEnviar" ).click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mID =$( "#id" ).val();
    var url="myget.php";
    var mData={id:mID};
    console.log(mData);
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: url,        
            method: "POST",  
            data: mData,
            dataType: "html" 
        });

        request.done(function(r) {
            console.log(r);
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert(`La petición falló ${textStatus}`);
        });
    });
});
```

---

## En el servidor

Un código similar al tuyo. La única diferencia es que he controlado el estado del POST y he probado incluso un `SELECT` para ver si funciona.

```
<?php
    $id=!empty(trim($_POST['id'])) ? trim($_POST['id']) : NULL;
    if ($id) {

        $server = 'localhost';
        $database = 'myprefix_'.$id;
        $username = 'myprefix_'.$id;
        $password = 'MyVeryVeryStrongPassword';

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $username , $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $rs=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM usuario")->fetchAll();
            var_dump($rs);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error en la conexión - Contacte con soporte    '.$e->getMessage() ;
        }

    } else {

        echo "Revise los datos posteados, no hay ID enviado desde el cliente";
    }
?>
```

---

## Imágenes de prueba

### Formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Resultado en la consola (se puede ver parte del `var_dump`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

## Conclusión

En mi caso, el código funciona sin problema ninguno.

Comment: Compañero, agradezco de corazon que te hayas tomado la molestia de ayudarme. He probado el codigo y funciona, sigo sin entender porque no funciona mediante el post comun, pero con  Ajax si funciona, incluso probe enviar mas parametros, y los recibe perfecto. Te mando un abrazo y muchas gracias!